# Tengo un problema al momento de recibir datos de un formulario en html a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, formularios, aplicación-web

Mi situación es la siguiente:
Tengo un formulario en html, el cuál capturo los datos y los mando a un archivo JavaScript, una vez aquí, quiero mandarlos a un php a que los procese para poderlos cargar en una base de datos.
Este es el formulario (el JQuery sí está cargado en la página):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje"></div>
            <label for="numeroControl">Número de control:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="numeroControl" id="numeroControl" autocomplete="on"><br>
            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirmar contraseña:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="idRol" id="idRol" value="3">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div><input type="reset" value="Salir"></div>
                <div><input type="submit" name="btnRegistrar" id="btnRegistrar" onclick="crearCuentaAlumno()"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Este es el script:

```
function crearCuentaAlumno() {
  var numeroControl = document.getElementById("numeroControl").value;
  var contrasena = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var confirmarContrasena = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
  var idRol = document.getElementById("idRol").value; 

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../php/correciones_registro.php",
     data: {
     idRol: idRol,
  numeroControl: numeroControl,
  password: contrasena,
  confirmPassword: confirmarContrasena,
},
success: function (response) {
  //$("#mensaje").html(response);
  alert("Dentro de AJAX");
},
error: function () {
  alert("Hubo un error");
},
```

});

Y este es el PHP (aún no lo conecto a la BD, primero quiero asegurarme de que recibe los datos desde AJAX):

```
<?php
session_start();
$idRol = $_POST['idRol'];
$numeroControl = $_POST['numeroControl'];
$contrasena = $_POST['password'];
$confirmarContrasena = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

?>
```

Ya comprobé que el botón de submit llamara a la función de crearCuentaAlumno(), también ya verifiqué que los datos se mandaran directamente del formulario al PHP.
Ahora el problema es que al momento de llegar al AJAX se pasa directamente al error.
Quiero saber por qué pasa eso, y qué me falta para que se pueda procesar la información.

Comment: Hola, podrias imprimir el error mediante un try catch asi ves que te retorna, ya que aqui te envia solo "hay un error", lo hiciste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu código y replicándolo, no veo nada extraño que te pueda generar error. Sin embargo, veo que dos cosas pueden estar mal:

1. En el código que compartiste, tu función `crearCuentaAlumno()` le
   falta un paréntesis de cierre.
2. ¿Esa ruta que pusiste en ajax es correcta? `"../php/correciones_registro.php"`. Intenta con `"php/correciones_registro.php"` y así debería estar entonces la ubicación de tus archivos:
   [image: directorio_imagenes]

Por cierto, ese archivo se llama ¿"correciones" o  "correcciones"? Quizá también esté mal el nombre del archivo con el nombre de la ruta que estás poniendo y por eso no lo encuentra. Es lo único extraño que veo por el que te daría error.

Todo eso lo podrías verificar en tu consola para depurar, en tus logs o con otros métodos. Por ejemplo, aquí te mostraría el error si al enviar tu formulario tienes un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

OJO, sólo que así como está tu código nunca te lo mostrará porque los submit se comportan por defecto (a pesar de que uses ajax) y recargan toda la página, lo que causará que te desaparezca rápido tu error, por lo que tendrás que incluir `event.preventDefault();` dentro de tu `function crearCuentaAlumno()` y así lo evitarás.

Ahora bien, si quieres refactorizar el código para que sea más legible y empieces a integrar el JQuery (ya que usas Ajax), quedaría así:

1. Agregamos un id para identificar al formulario.
2. Modificamos el input submit ya que después con JQuery lo vamos a accionar.
3. Con JQuery accionamos el evento cuando le den submit al formulario (igual en lugar de escribir campo por campo en la data para enviar, puedes enviar todo los inputs del formulario usando `serialize()`, aunque tu método también es válido)

**index.php**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form_crear_cuenta_alumno">
        <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje"></div>
        <label for="numeroControl">Número de control:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="numeroControl" id="numeroControl" autocomplete="on"><br>
        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirmar contraseña:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="idRol" id="idRol" value="3">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div><input type="reset" value="Salir"></div>
            <div><input type="submit"></div>
        </div>
</form>
<script>
$('#form_crear_cuenta_alumno').on('submit', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "correciones_registro.php",
             data: $('#form_crear_cuenta_alumno').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
            //$("#mensaje").html(response);
            alert(response);
            },
            error: function () {
            alert("Hubo un error");
            }
        });
      });
 </script>
```

Finalmente `correciones_registro.php` quedaría así para que verifiques lo que está regresando y eso se imprimiría en tu alert:

```
<?php

$idRol = $_POST['idRol'];
$numeroControl = $_POST['numeroControl'];
$contrasena = $_POST['password'];
$confirmarContrasena = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

echo $idRol." ".$numeroControl." ".$contrasena." ".$confirmarContrasena;
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! En efecto, tenía mal escrita la URL, sí era "correcciones.php", aunque también de lo que me di cuenta es que tengo que tener el script en el mismo archivo html. Lo tenía por separado en un archivo .js, y estuve corriendo el programa y me generaba el error. Hasta que puse el script dentro del html se pudieron procesar los valores. Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta.